# How I can make the Menu same this website www.chanel.com by using jquery

Tags: jquery

Hello I'm new of the jQuery,  I found this website http://www.chanel.com/ and I like them menu so much, Ex when it mouse hover it popup the image and when mouse out image is gone and and see the background, So can I do like this in Jquery by using something like this?

```
      <ul>
       <li id="pic1"> Link 1 </li>
       <li id="pic2"> Link 2 </li>
       <li id="pic3"> Link 3 </li>
      <ul>

     <div id="pic1"><img src="pic1"></div>
     <div id="pic2"><img src="pic2"></div>
     <div id="pic3"><img src="pic3"></div>
```

So how can i writhe the jQuery code please.

Best Regards

Comment: You are more or less asking for someone to code it for you, and hence it's not a real question. Learn the basics of [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) or pay someone to create it for you.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/show/, http://api.jquery.com/hide/

Answer (score 1):

Based on the HTML you post I would suggest to follow tutotials on both HTML as for jQuery.

E.g. your aren't using unique IDs for the elements in your HTML.

To help you go further, here are tutorial links, which I quickly found:

jQuery tutorial: http://net.tutsplus.com/articles/web-roundups/jquery-for-absolute-beginners-video-series/

HTML tutorial: http://www.tizag.com/htmlT/

Answer (score 1):

A good place to start would be [here](http://codrops.com) if I were you.  I've learnt a number of things from this website.  Plus the menu effect you're referring to has actually been used as an example on this site.  Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

first you should change the id of your three div like for example :

and then

```
enter code here

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#pic1").hover(function(){
$("#div1").show();
});
$("#pic2").hover(function(){
$("#div2").show();
});
$("#pic3").hover(function(){
$("#div3").show();
});
});
</script>
```